# Не могу установить pyinstaller в pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Помогите, столько не пробую всё одто и то же

PS C:\Users\Havanji\PycharmProjects\Havanji_Test> pip install PyInstaller
pip : Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняем
ой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пу
ти, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1

- pip install PyInstaller
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundExceptio  
  n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Попробуй Python - m pip

Comment: Выбивает только Python после этого и всё. Пробовал дальше всеравно ошыбка

Comment: "Выбивает только Python после этого и всё." - такое бывает, когда Python установлен через магазин microsoft, а не с официальлного сайта python.org

Answer (score 0):

оказалось нужно скачать wheel и после этого pyinstaller, сколько не смотрел  обзоров не находил.
И то, получилось не с первого раза, сначала нужно удалить pyinstaller, и если скачали wheel то и его тоже, потом скачать wheel а потом и pyinstaller.
Покрайней мере мне это помогло, один минус, если всетаки кинуть друзьям exe-шник ругаеться на вирусы, и если кинуть в VirusTotal получаю 10 компаний которые находят вирус

Comment: Мне не помогло. Переустанавливал, пробовал способ выше. Результат ноль.